# Passing variables from one file using include and to another file using href functions

Tags: php

I have a file "index.php" where I am creating a variable called $passdate which is a specific date I am calculating.  I am passing this variable to another file "calendar.php" using the include("calendar.php") function.  The variable $passdate doesn't physically exist in the calendar.php.  I am creating $catagory in calendar.php and defining it as "bar".  I want to pass both of these variables to a third file.  This is what I have.

```
<a href="calendarnew.php?todayis=<?php echo $passdate; ?>&catagory=<?php echo $catagory; ?>">
```

It is successfully passing the $catagory variable but not the $passdate because it actually resides in index.php.  I have been researching global variables but in the index.php file, the $passdate is generated within an IF statement and passes a different date through the include statement depending of which IF is selected.

I hope this makes sense to someone because I am lost.

The index.php file contains

```
 <?if ($weekday=="sun"){$passDate='2014/01/01';require("calendar.php"); ?>
```

the calendar.php file displays some content based on the passdate field.  Then it loads another file to display detailed information about that date within a specific catagory.  The catagory contains the value "bar".

```
 <a href="calendarnew.php?todayis=<? echo $passdate; ?>&catagory=<? echo $catagory; ?>">
```

If i echo $catagory in the calendrnew.php it shows "bar".
If i echo $passdate in the calendarnew.php it shows "".

There must be some way to pass a variable using include statements to a physical variable in the second file.  I just can't figure out how.

Comment: What about using the sessions? They can help

Comment: @Goikiu I wouldn't recommend sessions for this problem. We're going to need to see more of your code to make an intelligent suggestion.

Comment: If your variable is set before you include the file, it will be available in the included file just like any other variable you set in the include itself.

Comment: The variable is assigned before the include statement.  it does pass the variable to the calendar.php file but because I am using href to load the calendarnew.php file, it doesn't see the variable created in the original index.php, i will edit my post and include examples

Comment: @user3125362 PHP variables aren't shared across http requests.

Comment: Is there now way to assign a variable passed via include statements to the receiving file or is it just for viewing/functions within that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using an if statement, make sure you predefine the variable so you know if things go wrong

```
$myDate = 'bad stuff happened'; //Example.
$someVar = true; //Indicates a true value for the if in this example.

if ($someVar) {
    $myDate = new Date('Y-m-d'); //Today.
}
```

when passing this as `$_GET` parameters in a link, you can get a hold of these by using the describing word before the '=' sign, e.g. in index.php, if you want to call the date, you would have to call `$myDate`, however if you are in file 2, and lets say your url looks like this inside the link:

<a href="www.mydomain.com/?**todayis**=<?=$myDate?>&category=<?=$category?>" />click</a>

on the next page, you can access the date by using **`$_GET['todayis']`** since that is the name of the `$_GET` variable.

If none of these show up, you know for sure it's not getting passed to your next page.

Comment: thank you sidney, i will look at that.  but the main issue is that the variable assigned in the index.php file is not usable in the receiving or calendar.php file if i use the include function.  i need to pass the variable from index.php to calendar.php using include and then pass again to calendarnew.php using the a href you were just discussing.  any idea???

Comment: The issue is odd, if you have a variable set **BEFORE** the include, you can use it in there, otherwise I wouldn't know unfortunately :(